# Why doesn't my front_back programme in Python work?

Tags: python, str-replace

The task is:

> Given a string, return a new string where the first and last chars have been exchanged.

```
def front_back(str):

  if len(str)<=0:
    return str

  else:
    front=str[0]
    back=str[-1]
    new = str.replace(str[0], back)
    print new
    new_2=new.replace(new[-1], front)
    print new_2

front_back("code")
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It looks like you've got yourself a school homework and are in need of some assistance? I would suggest you ask your teacher or look it up in your study material and not fish for a complete answer on the interwebz. But if you are going to do so, please explain what part of the code isn't working for you, what the desired behavior is, perhaps even a stack trace showing the error you encountered and **most importantly**: What you've tried yourself to solve this issue.

Comment: The problem is in the second `replace`: it replaces all characters, not just the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why?

It won't work because `.replace()` will replace all occurrences of that character, not necessarily only the first and last

Below is a solution that constructs the string with first, body and last portions

```
text = 'code'
first, body, last = text[0], text[1:-1], text[-1]
result = last + body + first
# 'eodc'
```

Answer (score 1):

String literals can be *sliced* and *added*:

```
>>> s = "hello world"
>>> s[-1] + s[1:-1] + s[0]
'dello worlh'
```

P.S. `str` is a builtin in python, so using it as a variable name is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

First, *never* call a variable `str`.  Why?  Because that is the name of the class for Python strings.  If you use the same name then you loose it.  I use `txt`.

Your test with the length is sensible, but the lower limit can be increased (a single character would be silly).

But using `str.replace()` is not feasible.  Why?  Well it could work in your test case, but only because each character is unique.  `str.replace()` replaces *every* occurrence of the specified string.  So if the first or last character was repeated elsewhere then that would be changed as well.

You can use *slicing*, where the first (leftmost) character is 0 (zero).  You can also index from the right using negative numbers, so -1 is the last (rightmost) character.  The range of characters goes from the start to the character after the last.  So `[1:-1]` goes from the second character to the last but one.

```
def front_back(txt):

  if len(txt) <= 1:
     return txt
  else:
     new_txt = txt[-1] + txt[1:-1] + txt[0]
     return new_txt

print front_back("code")
```

I use `return` in the function, since that would be the normal way of processing text, and that is asked for in your question.